Langchain gemini ai doesn't have stream option like openAI during instance creation
How to add stream option with Google chat generative AI, as per Langchain doc they are using llm.stream() function, but how do i enable stream during instance creation and get token by token reponse instead of bulk response
//GeminiAI
llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(
    model="gemini-pro",
    safety_settings={
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
    },
)

//OpenAI
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0, model=MODEL_NAME, streaming=True,callbacks=[callback_f], api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY)


user can use llm.invloke() to get desired result.

Yeah that might work but I ended up using vertexAI to fix this issue
